# wrong center of mass x direction calculation (openCV Python)

Tags: python, opencv, center

I try to calculate the center of mass of objects in a binary image with openCV and Python. I use cv2.findContours and cv2.moments but I always get a wrong x direction. It has always a positive offset of a few pixels and I don't get why. I think I did it exactly like in the openCV doc.

Here is a example. Green is the contour found with cv2.findContours. Red the calculated center of mass.

[image]

My code is:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('C:/Users/Arno/Documents/Masterarbeit/Matlab/rect2.png', 0)
cimg = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
contours = cv2.findContours(img, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnt1 = contours[0]
cnt2 = contours[1]
cv2.drawContours(cimg, cnt2, -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)

M = cv2.moments(cnt1)
cx = int(M['m10']/M['m00'])
cy = int(M['m01']/M['m00'])

cv2.circle(cimg, (cx, cy), 1, (0, 0, 255), 2)
cv2.imshow('center of mass', cimg)
```

Comment: and what happens if you use: M = cv2.moments(cnt2)  instead of cnt1?

Comment: TypeError: array is not a numpy array, neither a scalar

Comment: It works with cnt2[0]. Thank you and sorry for the silly question..I'm a beginner in Python.